# In PostgreSQL, how to select rows which have a jsonb array with any element between a range?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the following (simplified) structure:

```
 id |            j            
----+-------------------------
  1 | {"price": [1, 2, 3, 4]}
  2 | {"price": [4, 5, 6, 7]}
  3 | {"something": "else"}
```

Ideally, I would like to query something like this:

```
select id from testjson where any(j->'price') between 5 and 8;
```

I managed to come up with a workaround:

```
select id from testjson where any_between(j->'price',5,8);
```

having previously defined the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_array_bigint(_j jsonb) RETURNS bigint[] AS
$$
SELECT array_agg(elem::text::bigint) FROM jsonb_array_elements(_j) AS elem
$$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION any_between(_j jsonb,lower bigint, higher bigint) RETURNS boolean AS
$$
select (lower <= any(arr) and higher >= any(arr)) from jsonb_array_bigint(_j) as arr  
$$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

This works, but is a bit hackish and doesn't look very efficient.
Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json_array_elements` to expand an array to rows:

```
select  distinct id
from    Table1
cross join    
        json_array_elements((j->'price')::json)
where   value::text::int between 5 and 8
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a75e7/4/0)  The example is for `json` instead of `jsonb` because SQL Fiddle doesn't yet support 9.4.

Comment: Interesting and clean approach. I can confirm that it also works with jsonb.
I'm just not sure about the performance, as it explodes the number of rows, and a distinct has to be used. I'll have to benchmark it with a bigger table, I guess. Thanks.